# css text-shadow clipping in select tag

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am trying to stylise a  menu using CSS and I am having an issue with the text-shadow effect clipping inside the dropdown. The text itself seems to be clipping inside the select borders, which is surprising because I would have thought that it would be allowed to spread into the padded area.

```css
    html,
    body {
        font-family: Calibri;
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: default;
    }

    #dropdown_user_select{
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: 25px;
    }

    select {
        background: none;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #555, 0px 0px 25px 0px #555 inset;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #555;
        text-align: center;
        transition: 0.4s all ease-out;
        font-size: 25px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
        cursor: auto;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background: #DDD;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    .cutoff {
        overflow: visible;
    }

    #arrow_down {
        /* a customised arrow on the left of the dropdown */
        border-width: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
        border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        top: 45px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="cutoff">
    <select id="dropdown_user_select">
        <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
        <option value="username">username</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div id="arrow_down" class="arrow_pointer"></div>
```

as you can see, I have tried to use a div with the overflow: visible to fix this but it has not worked.

**EDIT**

By clipping, I mean the text-shadow is cut off inside of the  tag. Here is an example that shows this better than the above:

```css
    html,
    body {
        font-family: Calibri;
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #dropdown_user_select{
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: 25px;
    }

    select {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 2px;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #F00;
        font-size: 25px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background: #FFF;
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

```html
<select id="dropdown_user_select">
    <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
    <option value="username">username</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you explain a bit?

Comment: Its because of the padding, the text shadow is going inside the padding

Comment: You have posted both CSS, and HTML. Why not make it a snippet, so we can see the problem, and perhaps do something about it?

Comment: @JonesJoseph I do not know hot to fix this though. should I just increase the height and width rather than the padding?

Comment: I dont think increasing width will solve this issue, only thign you can do it either remove the `text-shadow` or make the background-color matching the text shadow so that clipping is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that the `<option>` tag cannot have a padding itself, and the one set on the `select` actually pushes the left edge of the options, cutting off the shadow.

By using some trickery it seems to work on Chrome, it's not tested on other browsers although I assume it's fine.

The `text-indent` fixes the left shadow, while the `line-height` fixes the vertical shadows.

```css
select {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #F00; /* increased to test vertical cut */
    text-indent: 20px; /* fix the left shadow */
    line-height: 40px; /* fix the top/bottom shadows */
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0; /* removed left padding to compensate with indent */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #FFF;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown_user_select">
    <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
    <option value="username">username</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to figure out what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but if I read correctly, the text inside is clipping outside of the borders for you. Also, I wasn't sure what you meant by the shadows... here's a JSfiddle:

```css
html, body {
  font-family: Calibri;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: default;
}

#dropdown_user_select{
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}

select {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #555, 0px 0px 25px 0px #555;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #555;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.4s all ease-out;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 25px;
  cursor: auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #DDD;
  overflow: visible;
}

.cutoff {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#arrow_down {
  /* a customised arrow on the left of the dropdown */
  border-width: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cutoff">
  <select id="dropdown_user_select">
    <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
    <option value="username">username</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="arrow_down" class="arrow_pointer"></div>
```

I edited the `overflow` value in `.cutoff` and took away `inset` from your box shadow in `select`. I also edited your padding values to accommodate for the width of the down arrow. Not sure if that was what was happening, but I hope I helped.

If it's not what happened, please explain to me what did happen so I can try to help.

Comment: sorry, I did a poor job explaining the problem initially. I have just updated the question so there is a new snippet that illustrates the problem better

Comment: It doesn't look cut off in the snippet... what's the problem?